# Trying to edit the image in react-native-photo-editor but getting the error , cant find variable RNFS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

//IMporting the rn photo editor for editing the images

```
import { RNPhotoEditor } from 'react-native-photo-editor'
```

//options for picking the images

```
const options = {
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
}
```

//use effect for getting the permission

```
 useEffect(() => {
    this.getPermissionAsync()

  }, [this.getPermissionAsync])
```

//Storing image in the state

```
  const [ image, setImage ] = useState(null);
```

//Getting permission

```
getPermissionAsync = async () => {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
  }
```

//methods to pick and edit image

```
 const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(options)
      console.log(result);
      if(result) {
        setImage(result.uri);
      }
      }

  const editImage = async() => {
    console.log(image.replace('file://', ''))
    RNPhotoEditor.Edit({
      path:RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + image,
      hiddenControls: ["save"],
      onDone: (res) => {
          console.log('on done');
          self.setState({isRefresh: !this.state.isRefresh, imageHash: Date.now(), state: self.state});
      },
      onCancel: (res) => {
          console.log('on cancel');
          Alert.alert('', 'Edit Cancelled !')
      }
  });
  }
```

//React native view , selecting and editing image from here

```
<TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{marginVertical: 20}} onPress={() => pickImage()}>Gallery</Text>
      <Text style={{marginVertical: 20}}>Camera</Text>
      <Text style={{marginVertical: 25}} onPress={() => editImage()}>Edit Image</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

path:RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + image,

You should import it.
if you use expo , you code should like:

```
import {FileSystem} from 'expo'
```

for more detail please refer to expo's document
if you are without expo, your code should be:

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
```

but you must install it first and follow the instructions to config

Comment: Import it ??...from where ?

Comment: I think you have to install it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0

Comment: @KishanBharda imported it from react-native-fs, but throwing me an error of null is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot .
  Gives a pretty good quality output.
- Also you can use https://github.com/eneskarpuz/react-native-drag-text-editor for all text editing actions in your Photo Editor App.

  ```js
    ...
  import DragTextEditor from 'react-native-drag-text-editor';
  ...   
     <DragTextEditor
            minWidth={100}
            minHeight={100}
            w={200}
            h={200}
            x={WINDOW.width/4}
            y={WINDOW.height/3}
            FontColor={"#000000"}
            LineHeight={15}
            TextAlign={"left"}
            LetterSpacing={0}
            FontSize={15}
            isDraggable={true}
            isResizable={true}
            /> 
  ...
  ```